# What is wrong with this extremely simple regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to test that a regex will match a 2-digit number. I get:

```
11 =~ /^\d{1,2}$/
# => nil
```

Yet the regex works flawlessly on Rubular. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want exactly two digit ? In that case use `/^\d{2}$/`.

Comment: PS: `^` and `$` mean beginning and ending of *line* in Ruby, you almost always want `\A` and `\z` for beginning and ending of *string*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing the regex against a number and not a string. Regexes are intended for matching strings. Simply:

```
'11' =~ /^\d{1,2}$/
```

or

```
11.to_s =~ /^\d{1,2}$/
```

Comment: ✅ An interesting question is why `=~` doesn't raise an exception when sent to `11`. The simple answer is that it must be a `Fixnum` instance method. Sure enough, `Fixnum` inherits it from `Kernel` ( `Fixnum.instance_method(:=~).owner #=> Kernel`). The doc is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E). (`Kernel's` instance methods are document in `Object`). That method does nothing more than return `nil`. It does so in the event that the method is used in a class in which the method is not defined in the class' ancestor chain below `Kernel`. Why, I don't know.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is exactly what my answer is about.

Comment: @sawa, I should look through the other answers before posting a comment, but got sicktracked--didn't see your answer until now. I'll leave my comment, as someone seemed to have got something from it. (Of course the upticks could have just been for ✅.)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Kernel#=~`, which always returns `nil`.

Rubular does not interpret your input as Ruby code, it interprets is as string literal. That is why it works there.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying regex on number instead of string so convert it to string and try again.